# Hadoop - timed out when dropping a Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, drop-table, request-timed-out

I get an error when trying to drop a table in hive:

```
> drop table my_table;
```

Error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I also don't have the related data on the HDFS, what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Is table LOCKED, when trying to drop. Pls check table LOCK before running drop command

Comment: when running `UNLOCK TABLE <table>` I get an error: `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. unlock Table LockManager not specified`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the socket timeout:

```
set hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout=5000
```